# Cantor's theorem about countable sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Cantor's theorem states that no interval (a,b) can be the range of a sequence of real numbers. I know the proof for this theorem but I don't understand why this theorem is true. I mean can't we define a sequence ${f_n}$ as being $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow (0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}; f(n) = c$, for some constant $c$ in (a,b).

Comment: Aren't you assuming that you can put $\mathbb{N}$ in one-to-one correspondence with $(0,1)$ there? You cannot formulate a formal, one-to-one assignment of each $n$ with each number $c\in(a,b)$. Try to do it. You'll fail to be able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the *range* of $f$ has to be $(0, 1)$, not the *codomain*. The range of the $f$ you describe is just $\{c\}$.

Comment: Of course... thanks alot now it is clear

Comment: I thought range = codomain and that the way you're using range is as *image*. When did all this change?

Comment: @user4894 I have always seen "range" used to refer to the image, not the codomain. According to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)) this is the modern usage, and the term "range" used to be used interchangeably, but I don't know when this shift occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define such $f$ since $\operatorname{card} \mathbb{N}<\operatorname{card} (0,1)$.